# How to secure the default apache karaf installation

Tags: security, ssh-keys, apache-karaf

Following Christian Schneider's blog post, [How to hack into any default apache karaf installation](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2014/01/08/How+to+hack+into+any+default+apache+karaf+installation), I checked to see if my default Karaf installation (4.0.5) is insecure:

> Some simple steps to check if your karaf installations is open.
>
> - Check the "etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg" for the attribute sshPort. Note this port number. By default it is 8101
> - Do "ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost". Like expected it will ask for a password. This may also be dangerous if you do not change the default password but is quite obvious.
> - Now just do bin/client -a 8101. You will get a shell without supplying a password. If this works then your server is vulnerable

As expected. It is vulnerable. So I tried to secure it following the instructions as described:

> How to secure your server?
>
> - Simply remove the public key of the karaf user in the "etc/keys.properties". Unfortunately this will stop the bin/client command from working.
> - Also make sure you change the password of the karaf user in "etc/users.properties".

I shut down the Karaf server using the `halt` command. Then I changed the karaf password in `etc/users.properties` and deleted the file `etc/keys.properties`. Then I started the server again with `bin/karaf`. Then in a new terminal I tested to see if the installation was secure by trying to ssh into the server. I validated that ssh login now requires the newly configured password. Finally, I tried using the `bin/client -a 8101` command.

At this point, as explained in the blog post, I expected the command to fail:

> Unfortunately this will stop the bin/client command from working.

I noticed after running `bin/client -a 8101` there is a new file `etc/host.key` that either `bin/client` or the container itself auto generated. Rather than failing the command succeeded and I was presented with the Karaf console.

**Does this means the container is still vulnerable to this attack vector?**

Comment: I noticed a down-vote with a vote to close this question. Please explain the purpose for the down-vote in a comment.

Comment: Not the one who down-voted you, but I think you mean to ask: "How to secure... instead of how to hack...?

Comment: best to ask on the Karaf mailinglist, I'm sure you'll get a much more detailed answer there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

The modifications described in the OP *(changing the default password in `etc/users.properties` and deleting `etc/keys.properties`)* secures the container from that specific attack vector.

According to the discussion on the Karaf [users mailing list](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/How-to-secure-Karaf-td4047127.html) concerning this stack overflow question:

> By default `bin/client` tries (in this order) to use:
>
> 1. `etc/keys.properties`
> 2. `etc/users.properties`
> 3. `karaf/karaf`
> 4. `-u` to prompt for the password
>
> `bin/client` is an SSH client (written in Java). The `host.key` is the same file as for SSH and containing the trusted hosts (you also have `.sshkaraf/known_hosts` for that).

The section quoted from the blog in the OP is out dated:

> <strike>Unfortunately this will stop the bin/client command from working.</strike>